# Qt5WebKit module library is not built, when most others are built

Tags: c++, qt, arm, cross-platform, beagleboneblack

I am building the Qt opensource on Ubuntu Linux. The target platform is the BeagleBone Black. Build process itself runs successfully, but I do not find the libQt5Webkit.so in the /lib/ directory.

**Build and target platform details:**

- Host: Ubuntu Linux 15.04 x64
- Target Hardware: BeagleBone Black
- Target OS: Angstrom Linux
- Toolchain: arm-linux-gnueabi
- Qt Version: 5.4.2
- Build Command: ./configure -v -opensource -confirm-license -prefix
  /home/developer/projects/dependencies/qt/qt-5.4.2_Angstrom_BBB
  -device linux-beagleboard_angstrom-g++

I am not disabling any modules as evident from the ./configure command options.

**I have the following questions:**

1. Is the building of the QtWebKit module disabled / removed?
2. How do I enable building the QtWebKit module project?
3. How can I cross-compile only the QtWebKit project?

If more information is required, I will provide.
Thanks.

Comment: Possibly disabled if you don't have all the necessary dependencies that are required to build WebKit: ICU, perl, python, ruby, bison, flex... You should be able to figure that out by walking into the qtwebkit directory and running the (installed) `qmake` in there.

Comment: @peppe: Thanks. Will check on this. Could be the one of the few possible reasons.